# Time Total Session Time, send to user

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

Making a game in Twillio Flows

I'd like when the user enters in their first message, log the time, and when they enter in another message later in the flow the time is entered

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to work with this would be to use the [Set Variables widget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/set-variables) after you receive the message and use the [liquid template string "now"](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/user-guide/liquid-template-language#formatting-dates) to set the variable to the current time.

So, in the Set Variables widget name the variable something like `first_message` and set the value to

```
{{ 'now' }}
```

Then, do the same with a new variable name after the second message you receive.

Comment: Hey Phil, 

Thanks for this 


Im using this variable


You Started at:
{{widgets.send_and_reply_1.outbound.DateCreated | date: "%H %M"}} 


But it doesn't seem to be changing any of the formatting im getting

You Started at:
2022-06-23T13:08:47Z 

How do i get it so i can just have it saying 13:08?